# How read json within json in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I'm trying to read a json result, but I don't know how to read a json inside a json. I'm using the "json_nomalize" from pandas to read a part of the results, but I was unable to read the fields in contacts, such as: name, email, phone, cell phone, cell phone title

This is the json result:

```
{'totalSize': 1295,
 'done': True,
 'records': [{'attributes': {'type': 'Account',
    'url': '/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/xxxxxxxxx'},
   'Id': 'xxxxxxxxx',
   'Name': 'Empresa Teste_Mapeamento',
   'BillingStreet': 'Teste, 950',
   'BillingCity': 'São Paulo',
   'BillingState': 'SP',
   'BillingPostalCode': '00000-002',
   'CPF_ou_CNPJ__c': None,
   'Contacts': {'totalSize': 1,
    'done': True,
    'records': [{'attributes': {'type': 'Contact',
       'url': '/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Contact/xxxxxxxxx'},
      'Name': 'Teste_Testes',
      'Email': 'teste@teste.com.br',
      'Phone': '11 00000000',
      'MobilePhone': '11 00000000',
      'Title': None}]}},
```

This is what i did

```
r = r.json()
df = pd.json_normalize(r['records'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9wg5.png)

As result, i need a dataframe with this fields:

```
Id   Name   BillingStreet   BillingCity   BillingState   BillingPostalCode   CPF_ou_CNPJ__c   Contacts.Name   Contacts.Email   Contacts.Phone   Contacts.MobilePhone   Contacts.Title
```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: There's no JSON here anymore. This is just a `dict` whose values are other Python objects. Look at `df['records']`, `df['records'][0]`, etc. Just keep indexing until you reach the values you want.

Comment: @sammywemmy I updated with my expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(mydict, 
                       record_path=['records', 'Contacts', 'records'], 
                       meta=[['totalSize'], ['done'], ['records', 'Id'], ['records', 'Name']])
```

**Output**:

```
           Name               Email        Phone  MobilePhone Title attributes.type                                   attributes.url totalSize  done records.Id              records.Name
0  Teste_Testes  teste@teste.com.br  11 00000000  11 00000000  None         Contact  /services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Contact/xxxxxxxxx      1295  True  xxxxxxxxx  Empresa Teste_Mapeamento
```

Comment: Thanks for help me, but i think i did something wrong because i get this error:

`[...] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

My code:
`r = requests.get(queryUrl, headers=auth)
mydict = r.json()
df = pd.json_normalize(mydict, 
                       record_path=['records', 'Contacts', 'records'], 
                       meta=[['totalSize'], ['done'], ['records', 'Id'], ['records', 'Name']])`

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: Sorry, I did another test and it worked. The problem is that there aren't always records within the contacts, when there are no records, it shows the error above.

Comment: I got the same error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.
My code it is this way:

`df = pd.json_normalize(mydict, 
                       record_path=['records', 'Contacts', 'records'], 
                       meta=[['totalSize'], ['done'], ['records', 'Id'], ['records', 'Name']],
                       errors='ignore')`